# Trouble installing simple emacs tool

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp

Using the latest emacs 24.3 I want rainbow parenthesis for my lisp editing. I'm following the instructions on [this page](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RainbowDelimiters).

Here is what I get after I setup everything:

> File error: Cannot open load file, rainbow-delimiters
>
> To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
>   cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with the
>   `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace.

The byte compile proceded fine and created a .elc file. Is there a missing step in the instructions? How would emacs know where this compiled is located if there is no path mentioned anywhere in the .emacs file?

Comment: Not a missing step, but you missed the part in step 1 where it said "and add it to your emacs load-path." (probably because it didn't include example code). e.g.: `(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/lisp"))` if you keep your downloaded libraries in a `~/.emacs.d/lisp` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer I'm afraid but I would recommend [watching this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cf6tRBPbWKs) as rainbow-delimiters is available in MELPA and this will make managing Emacs extensions MUCH easier.

Comment: thanks, didn't realize it was in MELPA I should have looked there first.

Comment: strange that MELPA isn't mentioned in the installation pages http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RainbowDelimiters or anywhere else. But I got it working with MELPA thanks